# Every third element should have a date beside it

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

So I have been asking a lot of array based questions as I strive to understand PHP's main source of data structure.

I am currently working on building a class that spits out a list of artists and their songs. each third song has a date beside it. as seen in this array:

```
$music = array(
    'Creed' => array(
        'Human Clay' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Are You Ready'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'What If'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Beautiful',
                'date' => '2012'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Say I'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Wrong Way'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Faceless Man',
                'date' => '2013'

            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Never Die'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'With Arms Wide pen'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Higher',
                'date' => '1988'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Was Away Those Years'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Inside Us All'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Track 12',
                'date' => '1965'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

What I wrote was the following:

```
class Music{

    protected $_music = array();

    protected $_html = '';

    public function __construct(array $music){
        $this->_music = $music;
    }

    public function get_music(){
        $year = '';
        $this->_html .= '<d1>';

        foreach($this->_music as $artist=>$album){
            $this->_html .= '<dt>' . $artist . '</dt>';
            foreach($album as $track=>$song){
                foreach($song as $songTitle){
                    if(isset($songTitle['date']) && !empty($songTitle['date'])){
                        $year = '['.$songTitle['date'].']';
                    }
                    $this->_html .= '<dd>' . $songTitle['title'] . $year. '</dd>';

                }
            }
        }
        $this->_html .= '</d1>';

    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }

}

$object = new Music($music);
$object->get_music();

echo $object;
```

My question is that I end up getting something back that looks like this:

```
Creed
    Are You Ready
    What If
    Beautiful[2012]
    Say I[2012]
    Wrong Way[2012]
    Faceless Man[2013]
    Never Die[2013]
    With Arms Wide pen[2013]
    Higher[1988]
    Was Away Those Years[1988]
    Inside Us All[1988]
    Track 12[1965]
```

As you can see almost every song has a date beside it when in the array that is not the case. My question is whats the deal? I thought in my loop I was very clear in stating if this song has a year, set it and then print it beside the song title?

Can some one point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the date is not set for a song, the `year` variable is holding the value from the previous song (for which it was set). You are still actually telling it to print `year` next to the title, whether or not the date is set.

You need an `else` clause on the `if`:

```
if(isset($songTitle['date']) && !empty($songTitle['date'])){
    $year = '['.$songTitle['date'].']';
} else {
    $year = '';
}
```

This will clear out `year` when the date is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `$year` after you set it, so once you encounter the first year value in your array, you'll be constantly using that same year until a new one comes along:

```
                if(isset($songTitle['date']) && !empty($songTitle['date'])){
                    $year = '['.$songTitle['date'].']';
                } else {
                    $year = ''; /// reset year to blank
                }
```

And in somewhat unrelated stuff, this is probably a typo:

```
    $this->_html .= '<d1>';
                       ^--- number one? not letter L for a `<dl>` tag?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting year in foreach loop, so it is using last set year until value is reassigned. Here is corrected Music class.

```
class Music{

protected $_music = array();

protected $_html = '';

public function __construct(array $music){
    $this->_music = $music;
}

public function get_music(){
    $year = '';
    $this->_html .= '<d1>';

    foreach($this->_music as $artist=>$album){
        $this->_html .= '<dt>' . $artist . '</dt>';
        foreach($album as $track=>$song){
            foreach($song as $songTitle){
                if(isset($songTitle['date']) && !empty($songTitle['date'])){
                    $year = '['.$songTitle['date'].']';
                }
                $this->_html .= '<dd>' . $songTitle['title'] . $year. '</dd>';
                $year = "";
            }
        }
    }
    $this->_html .= '</d1>';

}

public function __toString(){
    return $this->_html;
}
```

}